# USB HID gadget "g_hid" in Linux on TIAM57xx

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, hid, texas-instruments, usb-hid

I want to test the linux usb HID gadget "g_hid" modules. But while inserting it is giving error as "no such device". After referring the Linux Documentation
http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.13.11/source/Documentation/usb/gadget_hid.txt, I got to know the **following code we need to add in the platform code**

```
#include <linux/platform_device.h>
#include <linux/usb/g_hid.h>

/* hid descriptor for a keyboard */
static struct hidg_func_descriptor my_hid_data = {
    .subclass       = 0, /* No subclass */
    .protocol       = 1, /* Keyboard */
    .report_length      = 8,
    .report_desc_length = 63,
    .report_desc        = {
        0x05, 0x01, /* USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)           */
        0x09, 0x06, /* USAGE (Keyboard)                       */
        0xa1, 0x01, /* COLLECTION (Application)               */
        0x05, 0x07, /*   USAGE_PAGE (Keyboard)                */
        0x19, 0xe0, /*   USAGE_MINIMUM (Keyboard LeftControl) */
        0x29, 0xe7, /*   USAGE_MAXIMUM (Keyboard Right GUI)   */
        0x15, 0x00, /*   LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)                  */
        0x25, 0x01, /*   LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1)                  */
        0x75, 0x01, /*   REPORT_SIZE (1)                      */
        0x95, 0x08, /*   REPORT_COUNT (8)                     */
        0x81, 0x02, /*   INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)                 */
        0x95, 0x01, /*   REPORT_COUNT (1)                     */
        0x75, 0x08, /*   REPORT_SIZE (8)                      */
        0x81, 0x03, /*   INPUT (Cnst,Var,Abs)                 */
        0x95, 0x05, /*   REPORT_COUNT (5)                     */
        0x75, 0x01, /*   REPORT_SIZE (1)                      */
        0x05, 0x08, /*   USAGE_PAGE (LEDs)                    */
        0x19, 0x01, /*   USAGE_MINIMUM (Num Lock)             */
        0x29, 0x05, /*   USAGE_MAXIMUM (Kana)                 */
        0x91, 0x02, /*   OUTPUT (Data,Var,Abs)                */
        0x95, 0x01, /*   REPORT_COUNT (1)                     */
        0x75, 0x03, /*   REPORT_SIZE (3)                      */
        0x91, 0x03, /*   OUTPUT (Cnst,Var,Abs)                */
        0x95, 0x06, /*   REPORT_COUNT (6)                     */
        0x75, 0x08, /*   REPORT_SIZE (8)                      */
        0x15, 0x00, /*   LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)                  */
        0x25, 0x65, /*   LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (101)                */
        0x05, 0x07, /*   USAGE_PAGE (Keyboard)                */
        0x19, 0x00, /*   USAGE_MINIMUM (Reserved)             */
        0x29, 0x65, /*   USAGE_MAXIMUM (Keyboard Application) */
        0x81, 0x00, /*   INPUT (Data,Ary,Abs)                 */
        0xc0        /* END_COLLECTION                         */
    }
};

static struct platform_device my_hid = {
    .name           = "hidg",
    .id         = 0,
    .num_resources      = 0,
    .resource       = 0,
    .dev.platform_data  = &my_hid_data,
 };
```

**Where shall I add the above code in Linux source code? I am using TI-AM57xx board.**

Comment: Please put more effort. Programming is not as simple as Ctrl-C → Ctrl-V.

Answer (score 0):

You **are not supposed to modify** any kernel source!

These `HID descriptors` are what goes into **your USB device firmware**.